# Direct calculation of the geodetic precession for the comoving observer

Tags: general-relativity, precession

In the text book "Gravity" written by Hartle (p.302), the precession angle per orbit of a gyroscope, initially lied in the equatorial plane and in the radial directon) moving in a circular orbit in the equatorial plane around a central spherical non-rotating mass) as measured by a stationary observer, is calculated (eq. (14.18)). In the next paragraph it is claimed that the precession angle of the gyro measured by the comoving observer is the same.
Honestly, I do not understand the reasoning. So I think I'd better calculate it directly for the comoving observer and see its equality with (14.18).
Would you please help me in the calculation? Or any explanation to understand the Hartle's reasoning?